# How to increment a struct? Associative array

Tags: loops, coldfusion

```
items = structNew();
for ( row in combo ) {
    //items['#row.ProdName#']['#row.SIZELONG#']['#row.COLOR#'] ++;
    items['#row.PRODID#']['#row.SIZEID#']['#row.COLORID#'] ++;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how many of each product I have, how many of each size, color, etc.  In php, the above code (essentially)  would work. However, CF is complaining about

```
"Element SOMESKU is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.
```

Do I have to keep testing with isDefined and define it?

Comment: What is the `++` for?

Comment: Also, what are you trying to accomplish? A struct is a key/value pairing. Your code looks like you are trying to create an array. And what is `combo` contain, an array?

Comment: Agreed. Maybe back up a few steps and explain 1) what `combo` represents and how it is populated and 2) post a sample of that data? While it is probably possible to make the code work, there may be better options.

Comment: As for "++" http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ffc.html it increments a variable, supposedly.

Comment: 'combo' is a query object.  Each row is a product, each column has info on that product: name, size, color, etc.

Comment: I think my examples below show how it might work if the productids are unique to your products and if they are not. Can you post a couple of rows from the table? Also, if possible, I would do this in the query, but I know that may not be possible. Also, if it's a query you can use Query of Queries.

Comment: If you can use aggregate functions on the query using QoQ it will be much faster than looping, especially if you have a lot of data. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff0.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7fcc

Comment: The main problem with your above code is you are essentially doing `null++` or `undefined++` since there is nothing to increment until it is defined.

Comment: (Edit - Did not see Leeish's response) Ignoring the question for a second, any reason you do not just run a query to calculate the totals? How is the data ultimately used? Just wondering if a structure is really needed here ...

Comment: What would be a quick way of posting the table rows for you to see?  It really is just a list of products with their attributes.  Your first example worked :)  There could be a few thousand rows.  Usually, a few hundered.

Comment: (Edit) Use cfdump to display the top 10 or so rows in the query, ie `<cfdump var="#combo#" format="text" top="10">` or <cfdump var="#combo#" format="html" top="10">. Then post the results here.  Also, this seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) :) Could you briefly summarize the overall goal first?

Comment: 1st, I get a list of orders.  I loop through those, looking for 'combos' or bundles, like CD + Tshirt.  For each of those combos, I need to add up how many CDs and how many of what size,color,design of tshirts.  So, each combo looks like:
[Record # 1] 
 COLORID: 0 
 PRODID: SomeBand30CD 
 SIZEID: 0 
 
 [Record # 2] 
 COLORID: 1 
 PRODID: SomeBand25T 
 SIZEID: 12 
I bet there is a way of doing all this either through straight sql or QoQ, but I'm not good at sql or coldfusion.

Comment: It would be more efficient to do that kind of aggregation in SQL. Then you are not wasting bandwidth pulling extra data across the network, and save time looping. If you post your DBMS and table ddl's I could suggest a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just trying to count, I think what you might do, using the code you have show is this:

```
items = structNew();
for ( row in combo ) {
    if(
        !structKeyExists(items,row.PRODID) ||
        !structKeyExists(items[row.PRODID],row.SIZEID) || 
        !structKeyExists(items[row.PRODID][row.SIZEID],row.COLORID)
    ){
        items['#row.PRODID#']['#row.SIZEID#']['#row.COLORID#'] = 1
    } else {
        items['#row.PRODID#']['#row.SIZEID#']['#row.COLORID#']++;
    }
}
```

So, what we are doing is saying, if any part of the struct we need doesn't exist, create it and make the value = 1. Otherwise, increment the value. You can't just do the third OR by itself because the other part of the struct won't exist to test on.

There might be better ways of doing this, but this will probably make the most sense to you based on your question.  You could do something like this:

```
items = structNew();
for ( row in combo ) {
    if(
        !structKeyExists(items,row.PRODID)
    ){
        items['#row.PRODID#'] = {
            color: row.COLORID,
            size: row.SIZEID,
            qty: 1
        }
    } else {
        items['#row.PRODID#']['qty']++;
    }
}
```

I think the second example is what you are going for if each product id is unique to the color/size combination. Then each `item` would be a struct that describes it with three values: `color, size, and quantity`.

Comment: All of this would depend on your data format. You could use a hashmap that would probably be even faster, but again, not sure what your `combo` data looks like.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to add up how many CDs and how many of what size,color,design
>   of tshirts

Generally, it is simpler and more efficient to use a query instead. Databases are specifically optimized for tasks like aggregating data. Offloading the work to the database engine eliminates the need for looping and saves bandwidth by only returning the data needed, rather than extra data that is ultimately discarded.

Without knowing your table structure or DBMS, it is hard offer specific query advice. However, essentially all that is needed is to select a few columns and aggregate by either quantity ordered or a `count(*)` of rows. The exact SQL depends on your table structure,  but the general idea is something like this:

```
SELECT ProdID
      , ProdName
      , SizeID
      , ColorID
      , SUM(Quantity) AS TotalItems
FROM  .... Your table(s) ....
WHERE .....
GROUP BY   
      ProdID
      , ProdName
      , SizeID
      , ColorID
```